# Avoiding copying large objects in R - does get() function make copy?

Tags: r

I have an inherited some R code that uses an idiom to avoid copying of large data frames. When a function that builds the data frame finishes, it does not return the data frame, but instead stores it in the global environment context:

```
assign(df_name, df, envir = globalenv())
```

After the function finishes, the calling code retrieves the data frame with this:

```
df <- get(df_name, envir = globalenv())
```

My question is this: does the `get()` function itself actually make a copy when it returns a value, thus creating the very copy that this idiom was meant to avoid? If so, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word, this is nonsense. What makes copies here are the *two* assignments (both via `assign` and `<-`). Just returning the object from the function would have saved one of the copies.

Incidentally, the copying itself is *cheap*, since R implements a concept called “[copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)” semantics: The commands above logically do make copies, but physically that only increases a reference counter inside the copied reference. The actual data behind the reference is copied only when you modify the data via one of the references.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, returning something doesn't actually copy it from one memory location to another.
A couple of tests:

```
trace_return <- function() {
  df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10])
  print(tracemem(df))
  df
}

ans <- trace_return()
# "<00000188C114D578>"
ans$a[1L] <- 0L # copy triggered on modify
# tracemem[0x00000188c114d578 -> 0x00000188c10ab098]: 
# tracemem[0x00000188c10ab098 -> 0x00000188c10ab258]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
# tracemem[0x00000188c10ab258 -> 0x00000188c10ab358]: $<-.data.frame $<-
```

And:

```
e <- new.env()
e$ans <- trace_return()
# "<00000188C13F8EF8>"
ans <- e$ans # no copy here
ans$b <- NULL
# tracemem[0x00000188c13f8ef8 -> 0x00000188c14293f8]: 
# tracemem[0x00000188c14293f8 -> 0x00000188c1429378]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
# tracemem[0x00000188c1429378 -> 0x00000188c1429278]: $<-.data.frame $<-
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not really matter if there are two copies of the identical data.frame. But to be honest I do not see any point to assign the data.frame twice.

You can use the `pryr` package to see how much memory an object allocates.

```
library(pryr)

df <- do.call(data.frame, replicate(8000, rep(FALSE, 8000), simplify=FALSE))

assign("dname_out", df, envir = globalenv())

mem_used()
337 MB

mem_change(df <- get("dname_out", envir = globalenv()))

736 B

> mem_used()
337 MB
```

The change in memory is only 736 Bytes, so actually you can not crash your pc with creating tons of copies.