does get() differ from passing an argument to a function?
Given a function which calls a function, e.g.
topfun <- function(x){
   y = 1:1e6
   result <- botfun(x,y)
}

botfun <- function(x,y)  return x * sum(y)

Versus, perhaps,
topfun <- function(x){
   y = 1:1e6
   result <- botfun(x)
}

botfun <- function(x) { 
  return(x + sum(get('y',envir = parent.frame()))
}

How many copies of y are created in each case (if any)?  Are there other memory or execution-time concerns?  Or, for that matter, am I going at this in a naive way?

Neither of these should create a copy of y as it's not being modified. Of course they both create a new vector for the return value but they don't act differently in this regard. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759117/what-exactly-is-copy-on-modify-semantics-in-r-and-where-is-the-canonical-source

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56382075/1968 and (for a more in-depth explanation) https://stackoverflow.com/a/78820242/1968.

As @SamR said in a comment, neither of those functions creates a new copy of y.  I would guess the first one (passing y as an argument) would be slightly faster, because you've got two function calls (parent.frame() and get()) in the second one.
Another possible way to write that code would be as
topfun <- function(x){
   botfun <- function(x) return(x * sum(y))
   y = 1:1e6
   result <- botfun(x)
}

I'm not sure, but I'd guess this is also a little slower than your first version, because R would have to search through two environments to find y.

The problem with this version is that  botfun is not visible anywhere but when topfun is executing.

That's a feature, not a bug! :-)
